# Ansible module - mount nfs share

Tags: linux, mount, ansible

I am looking for to make a "mount" on nfs share with ansible.
All I found is the "mount:" module that edits the fstab file.
I want to mount without rebooting.

Tx.

Comment: You shouldn't have to reboot once Ansible runs. You should try using the `mount -a` option once Ansible lays down the change in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: What do you mean by "without rebooting"? There is no need to reboot a server after you edited fstab

Comment: Can you please describe the bigger picture?  I'd like to understand what you're trying to achieve (over and above of the thing you're immediately asking for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer in documentation: [mount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/mount_module.html)

In simple words you need to set `state` to the `mounted`.

> If mounted, the device will be actively mounted and appropriately
>   configured in fstab.

Be careful with unmounting.

Comment: Tx Ivan. It's work!!!!!